# How to properly link to nodejs curve25519 library

Tags: javascript, node.js, curve-25519

I have cloned git repository https://github.com/thejh/node-curve25519 and next used `npm link` inside it. I am using this library in suggested way: `var curve = require('curve25519');`. But I am getting this error on the line `curve.makeSecretKey()` in this fragment:

```
temp.secret = crypto.randomBytes(32);
curve.makeSecretKey(temp.secret);
```

This is error message:

```
/Users/username/Workspaces/nodejs/myproject/server.js:59
curve.makeSecretKey(ctx.private);
      ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'makeSecretKey'
    at handlers.(anonymous function) (/Users/username/Workspaces/nodejs/myprojet/server.js:59:8)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/username/Workspaces/nodejs/myproject/server.js:198:3)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at UDP.onMessage (dgram.js:440:8)
```

What am I doing wrong? This library should contains such method. As you can see: https://github.com/thejh/node-curve25519/blob/master/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also link the library from your project directory.
An example from the [docs](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-link.html):

```
cd ~/projects/node-redis    # go into the package directory
npm link                    # creates global link
cd ~/projects/node-bloggy   # go into some other package directory.
npm link redis              # link-install the package
```

In your case, the first package directory is the `curve25519` git repo and if I understood your question correctly, the line you need to run in your project directory is `npm link curve25519`